# Unit testing firebase functions: how to stub firebase-admin sdk

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sinon

In index.js, I have the following

```
exports.write = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin.database()
        .ref(`xxx/yyy`)
        .push()
        .set({timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
    res.status(200).end();
});
```

In my test.js, I stub admin.database() as follows:

```
const refStub = sinon.stub();
setStub = sinon.stub();
refStub.withArgs('xxx/yyy').returns({push: () => ({key: 'fakeKey', set: setStub})});
databaseStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'database').get(() => {
    return () => {
      return {ref: refStub};
    };
  });
```

When I run my test, I get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'TIMESTAMP' of undefined`.  How do I fix this error or stub the call to `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you have `sinon.stub(admin, 'database').get` when you want to mock `set()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions can have properties.

```
> function x() {}
undefined
> x
[Function: x]
> x.prop = 1
1
> x
{ [Function: x] prop: 1 }
>
```

With that knowledge, stubbing admin.database is as simple as

```
var databaseStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'database').returns({ref: refStub});
//monkey patch database()'s property
admin.database.ServerValue = {TIMESTAMP: '1111'};
```

Credit goes to [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) for pointing it out to me on the firebase slack channel. Thanks Doug!

Answer (score 0):

`admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` isn't a call.  It's an object whose value never changes - a special value interpreted by the database on the server side.  If you print it, it looks like this:

```
{ '.sv': 'timestamp' }
```

Since it's essentially a constant value that never changes, it doesn't need to be mocked.

Also, it's not clear to me that you're using it correctly.  You're supposed to assign it as a value of an object that you write to Realtime Database.

Comment: hi Doug, thanks for responding. I've edited my post to make it clearer. Would you mind re-looking at it? Thanks.